# How to connect networks from different projects, VPC peering analogue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Google recommend to [use different projects to control access to resources](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations#projects-and-access) - ok, it seems reasonable

I plan to create one "shared" project with some infrastructure services and then several projects with resources which should have access to "shared" resources.

What proper way to connect them for free? (I know about Google Cloud VPN but it costs 36$/mo per tunnel)

Does Google Cloud Platform have (or planning to have) AWS VPC peering analogue?

Comment: Have you opened a discussion on Google groups as well?

Comment: @030 No, because I was a little embarrassed to go Google groups and ask for Google product feature with mention another vendor feature :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose, you can use [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shared-vpc/) (formerly known as XPN) for Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

Comment: Thank you, @Kamran. Do you know, Is it possible to contact Google Cloud Support to turn-on this future for testing on Bronze level support plan?

Comment: Shared VPC (formerly known as XPN) is GA now. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shared-vpc/

Answer (score 1):

`GCP` supports `VPC` peering now. Please take a look at:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/vpc-peering

Comment: thanks, I've already use it and this is exactly what I missed